# Mixed list ints and str into only int

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, integer

I am trying to eliminate the str from a list that the user gives, for example [1,a,3,k,k,9,p] I need to keep the list but then clean the str to then have a list of only int.
I have dont something like the code below, but I found out that the whole list is str
Thanks

```
if isinstance(x,int):
        print ('test')
        final_list.append(evaluation_list(x))
        print (mean(final_list))
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of such a list? Is it `[1,'a',3,'k','k',9,'p']` or `['1','a','3','k','k','9','p']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the user inputted only strings, and you want to convert those strings to integers, while filtering out the strings that cannot be converted to integers.

Converting a string to type `int` can be achieved by calling `int( )` on the string. If the conversion failed, exception `ValueError` will be raised. You can catch that exception in a `try`/`except` block.

```py
def map_to_int_or_discard(string_list):
  integer_list = []
  for x in string_list:
    try:
      integer_list.append(int(x))
    except ValueError:
      pass
  return integer_list
```

On the other, hand, if your list really contains values of type `int` and values of type `string`, then you can filter out the strings using `isinstance( , int)`:

```py
def keep_the_int(mixed_list):
  return [x for x in mixed_list if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your attempted solution is supposed to be, but if you have a list `li` you can filter out only the integers as such:

```
import numbers

int_li = [n for n in li if isinstance(n, numbers.Integral)]
```